# Goodix fingerprint driver

Tags: drivers, usb, fingerprint-reader

I have the following fingerprint driver

```shell
lsusb                         
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5385 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
```

I followed the following guide [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Goodix-fingerprint-Driver-for-Linux/td-p/8075018) and also used
`sudo pam-auth-update` to add fingerprint authentication as well, but I still don't see "Fingerprint Login" in my "Users" settings page. Is there something more needed to be done here?
My system is

```shell
lsb_release -a      
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and

```shell
uname -r
5.13.0-52-generic
```

Gnome is version 3.36.8

Any advice?

Comment: From what I can see, this specific model simply isn't supported. If anyone had found a workaround please do let me know. https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/No-driver-for-fingerprint-reader-Goodix-27c6-5381-on-Linux/td-p/8018706